# Qantas MEL-SYD-SCL: is the first leg international or domestic

Tags: air-travel, airports

I know checked luggage goes straight through, but how long in advance do I need to be at the Melbourne airport?

Comment: Who are you flying with? And what does your itinerary say about the terminals being used? (There are a handful of unusual flights in Australia which are domestic legs but using international terminals)

Answer (score 3):

The first leg is a domestic flight. Melbourne and Sydney are both in Australia. You should allow a few minutes of extra time for a passport and visa check which might be carried out at Melbourne, but apart from this it is no different than any other domestic flight. I would say arriving at the airport 60 minutes before departure is more than sufficient, 90 minutes if you are of the nervous disposition.

Comment: Note that there are a handful of flights within Australia which leave from International terminals, eg CX from Brisbane to Cairns